# Child window's move limited to parent window's geometry

Tags: python, events, pyqt5

I want to constrain child dialog window’s movement within the parent window’s geometry. If the child moves outside, the app places it on the parent’s boundary.

If I move the child quickly with the mouse and it goes out of bounds, my code works, but if I do it slowly, it doesn't. However, once out of bounds, if I move the parent window, the child is positioned correctly.

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import sys

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Mainwindow")
        self.setFixedSize(560, 720)
        self.resolution = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        self.move(int((self.resolution.width() - self.width()) / 2),
                  int((self.resolution.height() - self.height()) / 2))
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 660, 200, 30))
        self.button.setText("Insert window")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_new_window)

        self.w = None

    def moveEvent(self, event):
        if self.w:
           self.w.move(self.frameGeometry().topLeft() + self.windowsgap)

    def show_new_window(self):
        if not self.w:
            self.w = Ui_Progreso(self)

        self.windowsgap = QtCore.QPoint(int((self.width()-self.w.width())/2),
                                        int((self.height()-self.w.height())/2))
        self.w.move(self.frameGeometry().topLeft() +  self.windowsgap)
        
        self.w.exec()

class Ui_Progreso(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setFixedSize(320, 160)
        self.setWindowTitle("Window movement restriction test")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 280, 25))
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setText("Move window with mouse outside\n mainwindow bounds")
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-90, 110, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Yes |
                                          QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.No)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def moveEvent(self, event):
        if not window.geometry().contains(window.w.geometry()):
            wicoords = list(window.geometry().getCoords())
            wwcoords = list(window.w.geometry().getCoords())
            if wicoords[0] > wwcoords[0]:
                rx = wicoords[0]
            elif wicoords[2] < wwcoords[2]:
                rx = wicoords[2] - window.w.width()
            else:
                rx = wwcoords[0]
            if wicoords[1] > wwcoords[1]:
                ry = wicoords[1]
            elif wicoords[3] < wwcoords[3]:
                ry = wicoords[3] - window.w.height()
            else:
                ry = wwcoords[1] 

            r = QtCore.QRect(rx, ry, window.w.width(), window.w.height())
            window.w.setGeometry(r)

            return super().moveEvent(event)
 
        window.windowsgap = window.w.frameGeometry().topLeft() - \
                            window.frameGeometry().topLeft()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        pass

    def accept(self):
        pass

    def reject(self):
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

I tried to solve the problem with subwindows and found some interesting information about movement restriction in [QMdiArea, stop subwindows from leaving area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71917926/qmdiarea-stop-subwindows-from-leaving-area). Now the app works fine.

If anyone is interested in the subject, this is the final code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys

class Window2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window2, self).__init__()
        self.setObjectName("subWindow2")
        self.setWindowTitle("Window movement restriction test")
        self.setFixedSize(310, 120)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 285, 25))
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setText("Now window can not be moved with mouse" + 
                            "\noutside of mainwindow bounds")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Yes |
                                          QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.No)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonBox, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def accept(self):
        print("Yes........")
        
    def reject(self):
        self.parent().close()

class Window1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window1, self).__init__()
        self.setObjectName("subWindow1")
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #efefef')
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 620, 0, 0)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.pushButton.setText("Insert window")
        self.pushButton.setFixedSize(200, 30)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setObjectName("mainwindow")
        self.setWindowTitle("Mainwindow")
        self.setFixedSize(560, 720)
        self.mdiArea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea(self)
        self.mdiArea.setObjectName("mdiArea")
        self.mdiArea.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.resolution = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        self.move(int((self.resolution.width() - self.width()) / 2),
                  int((self.resolution.height() - self.height()) / 2))

        # Insert sub1
        self.sub1 = QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow()
        self.sub1.setWidget(Window1()) # widget)
        self.sub1.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.sub1.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.sub1)
        self.sub1.pushbutton = self.sub1.findChildren(QtWidgets.QPushButton)[0]
        self.sub1.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.showNewWindow)
        self.sub1.show()  

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow, "sub2"):
            event.ignore()
        else:
            event.accept()

    def showNewWindow(self):
        self.sub2 = QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow()
        self.sub2.setWidget(Window2()) # widget)
        self.sub2.setObjectName("sub2")
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.sub2)
        self.sub2.move(int((self.width()-self.sub2.width())/2),
                       int((self.height()-self.sub2.height())/2))
        self.sub2.installEventFilter(self)
        self.sub1.setEnabled(False)
        self.sub2.show()  

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if (event.type() == event.Move and
            obj.objectName() == "sub2" and
            self.sub2Restrict(obj, self.mdiArea.viewport().geometry())):
            return True
        if (event.type() == event.Close and
            obj.objectName() == "sub2" ):
            self.mdiArea.removeSubWindow(self.sub2)
            self.sub1.setEnabled(True)
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    # sub2 movement restrictions
    def sub2Restrict(self, window, viewGeo):
        winGeo = window.geometry()
        if not viewGeo.contains(winGeo):
            if winGeo.right() > viewGeo.right():
                winGeo.moveRight(viewGeo.right())
            if winGeo.x() < 0:
                winGeo.moveLeft(0)

            if winGeo.bottom() > viewGeo.bottom():
                winGeo.moveBottom(viewGeo.bottom())
            if winGeo.y() < 0:
                winGeo.moveTop(0)
            if winGeo != window.geometry():
                window.setGeometry(winGeo)
                return True
        return False            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You cannot completely rely on `moveEvent()` as there no absolute guarantee about when the event will actually be emitted; for example, in some systems and configurations, windows can be moved while just showing their outline and the movement is then "finalized" once the mouse button is released. One possibility could be to create a QTimer with a low interval (around 10ms may be enough) and eventually fix/update the position, but that wouldn't be very reliable. If you do not need to show the dialog as a *real* window, you could consider showing it as an *embedded* widget.